# Calculating remainder when a polynomial I'd divided by another polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility, euclidean-algorithm

> Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial such that when $p(x)$ is divided by $x - 19$ the remainder is $99$, and when $p(x)$ is divided by $x - 99$ remainder is $19$. 
>   Find the remainder when $p(x)$ is divided by $(x-19)(x-99)$.

I tried using the division algorithm but it can't be done that way, I am looking for ways that can be understood by senior high school student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $p(x)=(x-19)(x-99)q(x)+ax+b$, what do you get if you put $x=19$? And if you put $x=99$?

Answer (score -1):

You want a polynomial $p(x)$ such that
$$p(x)=(x-19)q_1(x)+99\qquad\text{ and }\qquad p(x)=(x-99)q_2(x)+19.$$
Then it follows that
$$(x-99)q_2(x)=p(x)-19=(x-19)q_1(x)+80,$$
and pluging in $x=99$ then shows that $q_1(99)=-1$. A simple candidate for $q_1(x)$ is then
$$q_1(x)=x-100,$$
and plugging this in yields
$$p(x)-19=(x-19)q_1(x)+80=(x-19)(x-100)+80=x^2-119x+1980.$$

Comment: We have found p(x), but we had to find the remainder when p(x) was divided with(x-19)(x-99)

Comment: @JordanLawson My bad, I hadn't read the question carefully. The answer is easy to find from my conclusion, but it's not the most efficient way to get there.